# How can I suppress a single instance of ReSharper's suggestion to convert my foreach loop to a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, resharper

Normally, if I disagree with some ReSharper-suggested code transformation, there is an option in the action list to suppress the suggestion by placing comments in the code.  The following are some examples of these comments:

```
// ReSharper disable UseObjectOrCollectionInitializer
var addresses = new MailAddressCollection();
// ReSharper restore UseObjectOrCollectionInitializer
```

and

```
// ReSharper disable ReturnTypeCanBeEnumerable.Local
private static MailAddressCollection GetEventStatusNotificationRecipients(UserAccountProfile submitter, 
    UserAccountProfile projectPrincipalInvestigator)
// ReSharper restore ReturnTypeCanBeEnumerable.Local
```

I don't know why, but the action list for the "Part of loop's body can be converted into LINQ-expression" rule does not include an option to suppress the ReSharper suggestion.  I already tried the transformation into a LINQ expression to see what sort of output it produces.  It turned a crystal-clear foreach loop into obfuscated garbage, so I reverted the change.  But, I'd like to be able to suppress the message.  Is there a way to suppress the suggestion (other than completely turning off the rule, which I don't want to do because there might be other instances where converting a loop body into a LINQ expression makes sense)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes any difference but what version of R# have you got installed?

Comment: I'm using ReSharper 7.1.25.234

Comment: This is most likely an omission on our part - would you mind reporting it to http://youtrack.jetbrains.net - thanks!

Comment: Dmitri - I just submitted a bug report to youtrack for this

Comment: I'll go farther and say most of the time a conversion to LINQ is harder to read than the original.  I revert probably 95% of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try to manually insert

```
// ReSharper disable LoopCanBePartlyConvertedToQuery
...
// ReSharper restore LoopCanBePartlyConvertedToQuery
```

around your code